# updating json value of a nested json array in a json file | Java

Tags: java, json, filewriter

I have this below json content in a file.

```
[
{
 "prjId": 1,
 "name" : "ABC",
 "issueCounter": 7,
  "issue": [
            {
          "id": 1,
          "status" : "Closed",
         "comment" : "blah blah blah",
          "loggedBy": "shdkjdlsj"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "status" : "Open",
          "comment": "nothing",
          "loggedBy": "xyz"
        }
    ]
},
{
  "prjId": 2,
  "name" : "XYZ",
  "issueCounter": 7,
  "issue": [
            {
              "id": 3,
              "status" : "Closed",
              "comment": "jjjjjjjj",
              "loggedBy": "klwm"
            },
            {
             "id": 4,
              "status" : "Closed",
              "comment": "test test test",
              "loggedBy": "NACK"
            }
        ]
}]
```

I am able to parse this file and then traverse this json to get to the node where i wish to update. Upon reaching that point, i am confused on how to update it so that it would reflect on file on filesystem.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

     JSONArray rootArray = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader(pathToFile+fileName));
     JSONObject project=null;

      for (Object rootEntry : rootArray)
      {
        project = (JSONObject) rootEntry;


        if( 1 == (Long) project.get("prjId"))
        {
            JSONArray issueArray = (JSONArray) project.get("issue");

            for (Object issueEntry : issueArray)
            {
                 JSONObject issue = (JSONObject) issueEntry;

                 System.out.println((Long) issue.get("id"));
                 if(2==(Long) issue.get("id"))
                 {
                     //now update the "comment" attribute here.

                     System.out.println("updated the comment: "+trckParam.getComment());
                 }
            }               
        }
```

I have just the json reader till this point so do I construct a String as-and-when I traverse the nodes and when i reach the point I need to update, I update it (and construct the remainder of the nodes in this json object, (not to break from the loop)) and then write the entire reconstructed string to same file? Or is there a better approach where I can traverse the JSONObject and once i update it, push the entire object onto a file without constructing a String of entire file.

I still need to figure out a way to take either of the approach. So any pointers or direction will be greatly helpful.

Comment: You can write it to a second file, and when you finish reading, close the reader and rename the new file to the same name as the old file. This is a better approach for large files. There is no way to change a text file in-place.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will write to temp file and then replace it to the original.